# QnA Maker - Azure Bot Service - Test in Web Chat not respondng

Tags: azure, testing, azure-qna-maker

First, new to creating Bots so please be patient.
I created a KB using QnAMaker.  Created new Bot in Azure Bot Service.  New bot was created using Template for QnA.  Followed the steps below per documentation:

> In Azure portal, open the newly created Web App Bot resource.
>   Click on "Application Settings" and in the App Settings list, add QnASubscriptionKey and QnAKnowledgebaseId. The corresponding values can be obtained from the KB Settings page in http://qnamaker.ai.
>   The QnAMaker-enabled Azure bot service app is now ready to use. To try it out click on "Test in Web Chat" to chat with your QnA bot.

**Test in Web Chat does not respond**

Also created new App, using Basic template.  Made to other updates.  Test in We Chat does send a response.

Again, new to the process but have read a great deal of documentation but nothing that speaks to this issue specifically.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I created a QnAMaker bot this weekend with Bot Service. The documentation is a little confusing at the moment, although Microsoft generally refines it over time until it's quite good. Here's what I did to get this going.

1. Provisioned a QnAMaker service at qnamaker.ai. I created a knowledge base, saved and retrained, and published. To make sure everything is good on the QnAMaker service, go to the Test tab (https://qnamaker.ai/Edit/Test?kbId=:your-service-id to make sure you can chat with it and it responds as expected.
2. Created a new Web App bot by going to the portal, clicking "Create a resource", choosing "AI + Cognitive Services", then "Web App Bot".
3. When entering the Web App Bot settings, I made sure to choose a Basic C# bot, and chose the "Question and Answer".
4. Once you provision the Web App Bot service, you'll also have a Web App provisioned as well. You'll need to create a web application that will answer requests from the web, hand them to your QnAMaker service, and return the results. Navigate to your Web App Bot service, then choose the Build menu option under Bot Management. Then Download the zip file containing your starter code.
5. Open the starter code. You'll need to add some keys to your web.config file. Make sure that you have  keys for the following, and that they're populated: MicrosoftAppId, MicrosoftAppPassword, QnaSubscriptionKey, QnAKnowledgebaseId, and AzureWebJobsStorage. If memory serves, these values are read within the code, but there's no empty stubs in the web.config that prompts you to enter them. This was a little frustrating.
6. After updating web.config, publish the web app to your Azure Web App instance associated with your bot.
7. Now go back to your Web App Bot in the portal. Under Bot Management, go to the Settings page. You're going to need to enter in the Messaging endpoint so that your bot service knows where to send HTTP requests to your web app, which will in turn talk to your QnAMaker service. In this example project, your messaging endpoint should be https://[web app name].azurewebsites.net/api/messages.

NOW you're ready to Test in Web Chat. Everything should link up then.

Comment: Thank you Rob for the quick response.  I made the suggested changes but still experiencing issues.  I am going to keep trying!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue just now.  It was caused by having extraneous data at the end of my QNA service key, something like (format=json) which somehow ended up after the key.  I suggest you re-copy and paste the knowledgebase id and key into the fields and make sure they are the correct length with no garbage.

Apart from not returning responses it gave no other clue as to what might be wrong.